# How to implement this jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality example correctly?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been trying to implement different examples of jQuery Autocomplete functionality, but none of them work.

The latest one that I have tried implementing is the following example, which seems to be the simplest jQuery Autocomplete functionality example:

Creating Auto Complete From a Hard Coded JavaScript Array
http://www.codedigest.com/posts/45/creating-autocomplete-textbox-in-aspnet-mvc

I added the following code in the @section localscripts section of /Shared/BaseTemplates/_Form.cshtml:

[Code in @section localScripts section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN9CW.jpg)

I then changed '#Country_Name' to '#FullName' and added div id="FullName" on the form that has the field that I want to implement the jQuery Autocomplete functionality on:

[Code in form that has the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsxV4.jpg)

I did not include the jquery-3.6.0.js script src in the @section localscripts section of /Shared/BaseTemplates/_Form.cshtml because it is already installed and being referenced else where. Even if I do add it, the jQuery Autocomplete functionality does not work.

This project is written in C# (MVC).

Comment: I was able to make the autocomplete solution work by using <input id="FullName" type="text" class="form-control"/> instead of Html.FormEditorFor. This brings up a new challenge of the value selected via the autocomplete field not saving to the database because it is not linked to a database attribute. I would like to use HtmlFormEditorFor or something else that links to the database attribute to save the autocomplete value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The final steps to obtain my solution were:

1. Remove -> div id="FullName" <- in the Form.cshtml that has the autocomplete field. 2. Change $("#FullName").autocomplete to $("#Street_Street_").autocomplete in the _Form.cshtml that has the @section localscripts section.

*Street is the name of the ViewModel and Street_ is the name of the attribute for the autocomplete field.